# Como poner imágenes en un GridView c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

E intentado de varias formas y no puedo colocar una imagen en mi gridview y nada que lo logro, no quiero poner una imagen cargada de una base de datos, quiero poner por ejemplo una imagen que este en mi computadora, mas un texto, pero solo logro poner el texto

Mira este es mi codigo, me jala la informacion de mercadolibre

```
protected void btnBuscar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
String busqueda = txtbusqueda.Text; 
var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MCO/search?q=" + busqueda + "&limit=5");
ApiMercadolibre obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); int total = ((ICollection)obj.results).Count; 
TextBox1.Text = obj.results[0].title.ToString(); 
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) { 
  tablita.Rows.Add(obj.results[i].id, obj.results[i].title, obj.results[i].price, GetImageFromUrl(obj.results[i].thumbnail), obj.results[i].seller_address.state.name, obj.results[i].seller_address.city.name, obj.results[i].seller_address.country.name); 
} 
tabla.DataSource = tablita; 
// DataSource asignar el origen de los datos, lo que quiero mostrar 
tabla.DataBind(); }
-----
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) { 
   tablita.Rows.Add(obj.results[i].id, obj.results[i].title, obj.results[i].price, GetImageFromUrl(obj.results[i].thumbnail), obj.results[i].seller_address.state.name, obj.results[i].seller_address.city.name, obj.results[i].seller_address.country.name); 
}
```

Esta parte llama a tdos los objetos, pero no me deja mostrar la imagen en el gridview, me aparece asi

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
No me muestra la imagen si no el texto

Comment: Donde esta el codigo donde intentas?

Comment: Hola @camilo, te sugiero colocar algo de código para entender tu pregunta. Te recomiendo leer este apartado para que tu pregunta no sea cerrada. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hay puse el código bro

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma de guardar y mostrar imágenes en un GridView, siempre les comento que guarden el archivo en el servidor y no crear un campo imagen en la tabla, ya que con el paso del tiempo la tabla se vuelve muy lenta para consultar.

Supongamos que tenemos un campo en la tabla con el nombre str_imagen y el campo contiene la siguiente ruta: "\imágenes\foto1.jpg"

Para poder visualiza la imagen en un GridView debemos insertar un campo en la propiedades del GridView y llama el nombre del campo de la tabla, también recomiendo poner el ancho y alto de la imagen en la propiedades ItemStyle del campo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bro pero en mi caso como hago ya que estoy creando las tablas por codigo c# DataTable tablita = new DataTable();-------------------------------------tablita.Columns.Add("Id");
            tablita.Columns.Add("Nombre");
            tablita.Columns.Add("Precio");
            tablita.Columns.Add("Imagen");
            tablita.Columns.Add("Ciudad");
            tablita.Columns.Add("Localidad");
            tablita.Columns.Add("Pais");,,, y necesito que la que dice imagen me la muestre, pero no lo hace